# Option/stock trading account for uk resident on US markets

Tags: united-states, united-kingdom, broker

I want to trade US stock and options and was wondering if I should be looking for a broker based in the US vs a broker in the UK. This way I would transfer currency to dollar. Also I believe there are more choices and flexibility this way.

The next problem would then be finding a suitable broker ;)

Any suggestions on approach?

Comment: Look into Interactive Brokers.  They offer trading in 200+ countries and their retail commissions schedule is among the lowest in the US.  I'd assume that it would be similar in other countries.

Answer (score 1):

Charles Schwab and Interactive Brokers (possibly others too) both offer accounts to UK residents, and allow trading US listed stocks and options. But specific recommendations are out of scope for this site I think.

Note that if you are not US-tax encumbered, it will almost certainly be vastly preferable for you to max out your stocks and shares ISA allowance first, though, even if it does not allow you to invest in options or individual US stocks directly.